# How many systems are there in the Galaxy far far away?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Irrespective of they are independent, Republican, or Separatist, how many systems are there in the Star Wars galaxy during the Clone Wars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**3.2 billion habitable star systems**

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_galaxy):

> Factoring in the output of heat and light needed for an advanced civilization to form, **there were 7.1 billion truly habitable stars within the Galaxy, and about 3.2 billion habitable star systems**. However, it was estimated that about one billion of those systems were actually populated.

Comment: Wookiepedia isn't canon

Comment: @DVK did I say it was?

Comment: that's what your answer reads like. If Wookiepedia has cites for this info, you should add them to the answer to make it clear it wasn't an invention of some random Wookiepedia editor (been known to happen :(