# Members of the Galactic Senate

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Does anyone know of where I can find a complete or semi-complete list of the systems that have representation in the Galactic Senate and the CIS? I'm attempting to write a Clone Wars Model United Nations background guide and in order do that, I need a decently-sized list of member systems in both factions.

Comment: This has the potential to be a large list, but I'm not sure it should be closed for that reason alone; someone who's more of a *Star Wars* expert is welcome to chime in, but for my money this list is reasonably-scoped (only senators during the Clone Wars), finite, and not likely to grow in the future (as Disney focuses on post-original trilogy materials)

Comment: aehem I don't think that a list would be under quite a few pages long. If you look at the number of seats in the senate scenes......there are a couple of thousands (minimum)? And the separatists...if they want to survive for more than a day they need also a couple of thousands there.......else the council is quite smaller (only those seen in star wars 3 I would guess during the scene with darth vader)

Comment: There are [hundreds to thousands of seats in the Senate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85327/31936) and presumably there's an approximately equal number of member systems.

Comment: @Thomas Agreed, but I find it unlikely (even in the *prolific* EU materials, and having done no research whatsoever) that more than a couple dozen worlds were mentioned by name

Comment: You only really care about two systems. Naboo (mainly because it is represented by Jar-Jar, Mrs. Psychopath's-wife, and Fyodor Dostoyevsky) and Brodo Asogi (more commongly known as "*E.T.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should get you started:

**[Member worlds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Republic-aligned_planets) of the Galactic Republic**

- [Alderaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alderaan)
- [Anaxes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anaxes)
- [Balmorra](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Balmorra)
- [Bothawui](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bothawui)
- [Chandrila](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chandrila)
- [Commenor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Commenor)
- [Corulag](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corulag)
- [Corellia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corellia)
- [Coruscant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant)
- [Eriadu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eriadu)
- [Ithor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ithor)
- [Kamino](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino)
- [Kashyyk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kashyyyk)
- [Kuat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kuat)
- [Malastare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Malastare)
- [Naboo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo)
- [Rendili](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rendili)
- [Uvena](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Uvena_Prime)
- [Xa Fel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xa_Fel)

**[Member worlds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems#Separatist_worlds) of the Confederacy of Independent Systems.**

- [Ando](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ando)
- [Bestine IV](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bestine_IV)
- [Boz Pity](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boz_Pity)
- [Cato Neimoidia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cato_Neimoidia)
- [Dac](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dac) (Mon Calamari)
- [Duro](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duro)
- [Falleen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Falleen_%28planet%29)
- [Felucia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Felucia)
- [Foerost](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Foerost)
- [Fondor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fondor)
- [Geonosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geonosis)
- [Hypori](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hypori)
- [Muunilinst](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Muunilinst)
- [Mygeeto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mygeeto)
- [Neimoidia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Neimoidia)
- [Rosha](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rosha)
- [Ryloth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ryloth)
- [Saleucami](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Saleucami)
- [Skako](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skako)
- [Sluis Van](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sluis_Van)
- [Sullust](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sullust)
- [Thyferra](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thyferra)
- [Vulpter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vulpter)
- [Yag'Dhul](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yag'Dhul)

Comment: answers should offer more than just links to other sites. at least summarize the most important information.

Comment: @phantom42 I've expanded on the post per your suggestion and I'll keep it in mind for the future, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the Asogians (E.T.'s species) be listed?

Comment: @WadCheber For the sake of brevity, I intentionally kept the lists short and tried to only include planets of the most note/importance (though the links in each header provides further examples, over 600 in the case of the Republic).  
Brodo Asogi, home planet to the Asogians, is located in the Outer Rim so I wouldn't suspect that they'd have much political pull and I don't believe, outside of being a neat reference/inclusion, they've done anything of note.

Comment: @Antillies - They did send a mission to earth, and built an intergalactic telephone out of a spin and say.  But fair enough.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In canon, we know of the following members:

- [Vice Chair](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vice_Chair/Canon)
- [Padmé Amidala](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala/Canon)
- [Bail Antilles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bail_Antilles/Canon)
- [Lott Dod](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lott_Dod/Canon)
- [Onaconda Farr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Onaconda_Farr/Canon)
- [Bail Organa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bail_Organa)
- [Sheev Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious)
- [Ainlee Teem](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ainlee_Teem/Canon)

([Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Senate/Canon))

In Legends, though, we also know of:

- [Mon Mothma](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mon_Mothma)
- [Orn Free Taa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Orn_Free_Taa)
- [Stonk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stonk)

([Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Senate))

These are the actual *individual members* we know of.  There's plenty more who we don't know about and I'm sure that @Antillies' answer will be of great use there!