# How many systems were part of the Republic?

Tags: star-wars

In the opening crawl for *Attack of the clones* we learn that:

> Several thousand solar systems have declared their intentions to leave the Republic.

**How many solar systems were part of the Republic in the first place?**

And, if someone would happen to know; **How many systems actually left the Republic?**

Comment: I think there was a similar question already in the past asking for a list of separatist systems

Comment: Possible, though I didn't find it when I searched. And what I really want to know is how many are part of the Republic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "[Making of Star Wars - The Definitive Story Behind the Original Film"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Making_of_Star_Wars:_The_Definitive_Story_Behind_the_Original_Film) factbook, George Lucas gave some additional (albeit now non-canon) detail about the Galactic Senate:

> **LEIA ON THE HISTORY OF THE EMPIRE**
>   *"In the Old Republic, all the systems sent their representatives to the Senate. It wasn't an Imperial Senate; it was a Republican Senate,
>   which made the decisions that controlled the Republic. **There were
>   24,372 systems in the Galactic Senate.** The Senate would vote in a
>   Chancellor or an overseer who would work for four years as the leader
>   of the executive branch of the Republic. You were only supposed to be
>   able to run for one four-year term — you were only eligible for one
>   term.”*

Given that the Republic's "[Grand Convocation Chamber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Convocation_Chamber)" only seats 1024, it stands to reason that a large proportion of the systems in the Republic choose to *share* representation with other systems. This number also doesn't seem to include what would presumably be a truly vast number of populated moons, asteroids and planetary colonies that are represented by their home planets.

Comment: And they put all the necessary working parts on one, well-known planet. Well done.

Comment: @axelrod - You gotta put it somewhere :-)