# Who was part of the Galactic Senate during Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

Who was in the Senate during *The Phantom Menace*?

Comment: Given that [there are 2372 member systems](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115913/5184), I think this may be a little broad/list question.

Comment: @phantom42 - 24,372, actually.

Comment: whoops. typo. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Why, the senators, naturally. Plus the guy that maintains all the floaty dais-things.

Comment: The floaty dais repairman has a seventeen-part EU novel series to explain his backstory.